# How to spin 2D vector clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Tags: python, numpy, math, vector

I am trying to rotate a unitary vector A oriented on the Y axis according to a database of instruction.

The vector is described as ( (x1 , x2) , ( y1 , y2 ).

```
A = np.array([ 0 ,0 ] , [ 0 , 1 ] )
Database = ['left', 'right', 'right', ... ]
```

If , for example we spin 4 times clockwise we are supposed to get :

```
#First spin
[(0,1),(0,0)]
#Second spin
[(0,0),(0,-1)]
#third spin
[(0,-1),(0,0)]]
#fourth spin
[(0,0),(0,1)]
```

Comment: I editted the array.

Comment: So now it's not a vector anymore. Neither is `(0,0)` a unit vector. If you orient a vector `(x, y) = (0,1)` counter-clockwise, you will get `(0,1) -> (-1,0) -> (0,-1) -> (1,0)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can rotate a vector by multiplying it with a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). The given example rotates the initial vector by 30 degrees counter-clockwise (as positive angles do in a cartesian coordinate system):

```
A = np.array([ 0 , 1])

theta = np.radians(30)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
R = np.array(((c,-s), (s, c)))

A = np.dot(R, A)
```